# Change Path Python Created File

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, path

When I create a file like .txt or .db with Python code, the file is always **created in root directory and not in my current directory.**
Does anyone have an idea of how can I change the path of a created file in Python with Visual Studio Code?

I know I can do this with os module or with adding code lines, but I want to set it up by default in Visual Studio.

[This is my current configuration in launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlcGv.png)

[This is what I get when I debug with F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9jpM.png)

Comment: probably, you need to set the workspace to the right directory. You can also use absolute path to create a file in a defined directory.

Comment: Yes, I can also do that but I have few directories in my workspace so I can't just use one. 
How can I use absolute path to create a file in a defined directory?

Comment: you can just prefix the path in the file name before creating/writing to a file. please share your code if you are not clear.

Comment: Ah okay I understand, I know that but I don't want to do like this. I want to set it up my default settings.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, when we run the code generation file, the VS Code terminal enters the project root directory by default (the command to run the file is executed here):

[image]

In VS Code, when we run the code generation file, the VS Code terminal enters the project root directory by default (the command to run the file is executed here):

Method 1:

Please "cd" to the folder you need before running the python script:

[image]

Method 2:

Please modify the debugging path to the file you need: please use the following settings in "launch.json": `"cwd": "${fileDirname}",` then click `F5`:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it seems to be the solution but I couldn't reach the way to change python terminal path. I could change the bash terminal path but not the python terminal path. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @adam_paris -Do you mean method 1 in my answer? You could run the code first and then use _cd_ to the folder you need in the terminal where it runs (Since VS Code runs in this Python terminal by default.). If it still doesn't work, please let me know so that I can help you in time.

Comment: Thanks. No I mean 2nd method, I want to change the path in the JSON file.

Comment: @adam_paris -When you use "cwd": "${fileDirname}" in "launch.json", then click _F5_, does it not work? And when _F5_ to debug the code, it will output in the "Python debug console" terminal.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Look at the situation on my first post, I've added screenshots.

Comment: @adam_paris -In the second screenshot you provided, it seems that the setting file "launch.json" is being debugged.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with Python? Because I delete the last line and debug again but I still have the same error. I'll try to uninstall and re-install Python.

Comment: @adam_paris  -I mean please debug your python file (.py) instead of debugging the "launch.json" file.

Comment: I've uninstall and re-install many times with different versions but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah okay I have misunderstood. I've also debugged my current python file (libary.py) but any problem appears.

Comment: @adam_paris -What is displayed on the VS Code terminal after debugging the python code? (Please overwrite personal information such as user name.)

Comment: `Mac-mini:[folder-name] macmini$  /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/macmini/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.1.502429796/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 50291 -- "/Users/macmini/Desktop/[folder-name]/libary.py" 
Mac-mini:[folder-name] macmini$ `

Comment: @adam_paris  -It seems that the code runs successfully. (These paths are all required for running.)  Is the .txt file generated in the required folder now?

Comment: Unfortunately, the file is created in the root directory.

Comment: @adam_paris -Is "cwd" in "launch.json" already "${fileDirname}"? Please provide us with the location of your python file in the project and the folder location where you want the txt file to exist.

Comment: My "launch.json" file: { "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ { "name": "Python: Current File", "type": "python", "request": "launch", "program": "${file}", "console": "integratedTerminal", "cwd": "${fileDirname}" } ] }  
location: root folder > folder1 > python |
file created file location: root folder > test.txt |  
wanted file location: root folder > folder1 > test.txt

Comment: @adam_paris -This is strange. It is recommended that you try to kill the current terminal in VS Code, and then use the shortcut key " Ctrl+Shift+` " to open a new VS Code terminal, or reinstall the Python extension and reload VS Code, and then click F5 to debug the code.

Comment: I made this a lot of time but unfornatly it's didn't work. Thanks a lot for your help, and your time :)

Comment: @adam_paris  -If you need more help, you could describe your current problem in detail in the thread or create a new thread.

Comment: Okay thanks. Now I just open the current folder without the others folders and it's working.

Comment: In fact you helped me a lot but it doesn't solves my problem...